# I want to know the exact file/location of this text that shows on add/edit product from Admin.?

Tags: magento2

[Here is image attatch and text is visible that i want to know from where comes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nC05.png)

Answer (score 0):

From this file

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php